# PDPage getResources() not showing jp2 PDImageXObject

Tags: android, pdfbox

I am trying to extract images from PDF using Apache PDFBOX for android
But I am not able to extract .jp2 images from the pdf
While it is present in the pdf

I am using this code to get images from PDPage

```
PDResources res = page.getResources();

for(COSName c: res.getXObjectNames()){
     PDXObject xObject = page.getResources().getXObject(c);
     if(xObject instanceof PDImageXObject){
         PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject) xObject;
         // Some code here
     }
```

Its not showing jp2 images
Please help

Comment: Is the JPEG2000 decoder in your classpath? https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html

Comment: And are you sure the images in question are immediately in the page resources and not in the resources of some form Xobject or pattern of the page?

Comment: Also have a look at the source code of ExtractImages.java in the source code download. Getting all the images from a PDF is more complex than your code, sadly.

Comment: I tried recursively also for FormXObject, not image object was there

Comment: Will look into ExtractImages.java 
I have not done this one JPEG2000 decoder in your classpath?
Any help how to do this for Android Tom_Roush port of PDFBox?

Comment: I'm with the desktop project, sorry, I don't know if a dependency is needed for JPEG2000 there (please look at any log messages). Please share your PDF (link to it).